# Data-binding input[radio] that has button template (switch) AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, radio-button

Why is data binding not working on my radio button working as switch in angular?

I have this form:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="false" ng-model="genData.status"> Inactive
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="true" ng-model="genData.status"> Active
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="generate()">Generate</button>
```

renders this switch:

[image]

in my js controller i have initialized the switch but it doesnt reflect the view:

```
$scope.genData = {};
$scope.genData.status = false;
```

everytime i submit the form, status always returns `false` disregarding if it is inactive or active in switch.

```
$scope.generate = function() {
    console.log($scope.genData.status); // this is always false, dont know why
}
```

therefore the toggle doesnt update the scope?

Answer (score 0):

You are relating a `boolean` to a `string` it can be fixed:

```
$scope.genData.status = 'false';
```

Comment: Also what does the form submission function look like?

Comment: from the code provided there is nothing that I can see that is blocking the scope from updating, I updated the pen to mirror what you have:http://codepen.io/LoganArnett/pen/XNRaZL

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by this alternative

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" ng-if="genData.status === true">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="false" ng-model="genData.status"> Inactive
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="true" ng-model="genData.status"> Active
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" ng-if="genData.status === false">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="false" ng-model="genData.status"> Inactive
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="true" ng-model="genData.status"> Active
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="generate()">Generate</button>
```

I've used ng-if to check of true or false the gen-data.status then switched the css class btn-default to btn-primary if the gendata.status === true

and if false will go to btn-default.

I'm not good in english, just look at the code ^_^